# Usage of Simplefonts

Tags: context

after installation of standalone context I tried to compile the following MWE:

```
\setupbodyfontenvironment[default][em=italic]

\usemodule[simplefonts][size=10pt]

\setmainfont[Constantia]

\starttext

Serif typeface: regular, {\em italic}, {\bf bold} and {\bf\em bold italic} fonts.

\stoptext
```

It works, but I got a failure like
tex error on line 802 in file c:/.../t-simplefonts.mkiv: ! Undefined control sequence.

After pressing the "s" the compilation works.

How to prevent this?

Best regards,
Thomas

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Could you please post the complete error message (including the one about the undefined control sequence)?

Comment: I thought the simplefonts module was [deprecated](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/simplefonts).

Comment: Are you the same Thomas as this guy? https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/168494/thomas If yes, it looks like you've got two separate accounts. The Stack Exchange staff can [merge them together for you](//tex.stackexchange.com/help/user-merge).

Answer (score 5):

Add `\letvalue{@NX}\noexpand` before `\usemodule[simplefonts]`.  It seems like the `\@NX` variable was removed from the core.

```
\setupbodyfontenvironment[default][em=italic]

\letvalue{@NX}\noexpand
\usemodule[simplefonts][size=10pt]

\setmainfont[Constantia]

\starttext

Serif typeface: regular, {\em italic}, {\bf bold} and {\bf\em bold italic} fonts.

\stoptext
```

In other news, `simplefonts` has been deprecated and you should use `\definefontfamily` nowadays.

```
\setupbodyfontenvironment[default][em=italic]

\definefontfamily[mainface][rm][Constantia]
\setupbodyfont[mainface]

\starttext

Serif typeface: regular, {\em italic}, {\bf bold} and {\bf\em bold italic} fonts.

\stoptext
```